# Javascript chart one number step

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts, chart.js

I have problem with javascript chart, where the number not iterate by 1, but 0.5 (check screen bellow)

[image]

345 - 34,5.5 - 346 - 34,6.5

I want this

345 - 346 - 347

I have this code:

```
 let followers_chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('followers_chart').getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: <?= $logs_chart['labels'] ?>,
        datasets: [{
            label: '<?= $language->report->display->followers ?>',
            data: <?= $logs_chart['followers'] ?>,
            backgroundColor: '#ED4956',
            borderColor: '#ED4956',
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            callbacks: {
                label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
                    let value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
                    value = value.toString();
                    value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                    value = value.join(' ');
                    return value;
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: '<?= $language->report->display->followers_chart ?>',
            display: true
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    userCallback: (value, index, values) => {
                        // Convert the number to a string and splite the string every 3 charaters from the end
                        value = value.toString();
                        value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                        value = value.join(' ');
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

The second problem is, that the top and bottom line are not visible full. Where may I change this in code and which file? Im total noob at JavaScript :D

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, I think you can write in `scales > yAxes > ticks`, the parameter `stepSize` and assign it to `1`. 
For the second question, try to put in `scales > yAxes > ticks`, the parameter `stepSize` and min and max to the min or max value of `$logs_chart['followers']`.

```
yAxes: [{
   ticks: {
       stepSize: 1,
       min: <?= intval(min($logs_chart['followers'])) - 0.5 ?>,
       max: <?= intval(max($logs_chart['followers'])) + 0.5 ?>
   }
}]
```

Wish it helped you

Comment: if (Math.floor(value) === value) { --- this was helped to me with steps 1. But the line is still cut (tried your solution, but not working) :/

Answer (score 1):

In your scales definition just try adding the following :

```
ticks: {
            min: 0,
            beginAtZero: true
}
```

That will at least ensure that you can see the bottom line.

Comment: And for the TOP line? if (Math.floor(value) === value) { --- this was helped to me with steps 1. But need bottom/top line +1 (to not be cuted).